# Highlight alternate rows with logic:iterate

Tags: jsp, struts

Below code gives me rows with the same color. How to highlight alternate rows in this table with same color

```
<logic:iterate id="ulist" name="HomeForm" property="userList">
  <tr >
    <td class="content"><bean:write name="ulist" property="username"  />&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="content"><bean:write name="ulist" property="city"  />&nbsp;</td>
</tr>   
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: Use JSTL when functionality overlaps with the Struts 1 tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using this code:

```
<logic:iterate id="myData" name="myListFormBean" property="myList" indexId="tableCounter">
<%
if (tableCounter % 2 == 0) {
    tdClass = " white ";
} else {
    tdClass = " gray ";
}
%>
    <td class="<%=tdClass%>"></td>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: Well, you can use JSTL `c:out` or stuff like that if you like.

Answer (score 4):

Code without scriplet

```
<logic:iterate id="myData" name="myListFormBean" property="myList" indexId="tableCounter">
    <tr class="${tableCounter%2==0 ? 'Even':'Odd'}">
</logic:iterate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to assign a differente `css` `id` for every row, you can use the implicit iterator attributes to obtain that.

Another solution is to use a library like [displaytag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/) which automatically adds `odd` and `even` attributes to the rows, attributes you can use in the `css` stylesheet.